# How would one configure a Gradle project in which a subproject depends on the main project?

Tags: java, gradle, project-management, project-structure, multi-project

I have a mini-application in my source code which I am trying to move to a separate subproject. However, the mini-application depends on the main project. How would one set up a `build.gradle` file to reflect this?

Here is my directory structure:

```
/
    src/
        main/java/<main project source>
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
    subproject/
        src/
            main/java/<subproject source>
        build.gradle
```

I was thinking that one could do something like this in the `build.gradle` file for the subproject:

```
build.dependsOn ":build"
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: could you elaborate on what you mean by 'he mini-application depends on the main project' here?

Comment: @PerryFowler Essentially, the main project is a library and the subproject is an implementation of that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up compile dependencies correctly for this to work.

The statement `build.dependsOn ":build"` will only set up task dependencies (i.e. that :subproject:build is executed after main project ":build"). This is probably not necessary, main project build is executed before subproject builds anyway. It will not set up compile dependencies (i.e. which classes/libraries to include).

Instead (or in addition) add a compile dependency to your main project in your `subproject/build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':')
}
```